# converting a set of strings to a json in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, split

I am currently working on setting up a flask server for my front end. The request I get is in the form the following JSON object:

```
InputJson = {"text":"Field1:A|Field2:B|Field3:C","format":"Reader"}
```

I would like to convert the text field to a proper JSON:

```
OutputJson = {"Field1":"A","Field2":"B","Field3":"C"}
```

What I did so far:
I first replaced the pipes using `string.replace` in python. However, I end up with a plain string which I am not able to convert to json.

I have tried using `json.loads` on the cleaned string (I replaced the `|` with `,`.

Any help here would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split your string on "|", then split each part on ":", feeding the pairs into a dict:

```
output = dict( keyvalue.split(':') for keyvalue in orig_value.split('|') )
```

You don't need to use any json-parsing tools for that, because the format of the string you're parsing has nothing to do with json formatting.